# Python Export/Download SugarCRM report

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests, sugarcrm

I want to export or download a SugarCRM report from the reports folder to a data frame or to a CSV directly using python without logging into the CRM and exporting it. The rest API v10 gave me a successful token and I was able to run a custom query. But I am unable to get the report from the API.

Is there a way we can achieve this?

The get_report method for SugarCRM (Sugar CRM API wrapper) is not yet available as per the website.

```
url = "https://mydomain.sugarondemand.com/rest/v10/oauth2/token"
payload = {"grant_type":"password","username":"ursername","password":"password","client_id":"sugar"}


r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))

response = json.loads(r.text)    
print ('Success! OAuth token is ' + token)
```